# Using RegExp to filter receipt for prices

Tags: javascript, regex

With my programm I want to be able to make a picture of any receipt and filter certain informations, one beeing the price.

My Input is the following:

#### Input:

```
----------
BT em <br/>
SCHWEINFURT _OSKAR-VON-MILLER-STR.6 <br/>
RADIESCHEN **0,59** <br/>
KAESEAUFSCH. **1.39** <br/>
BAUCHSPECK **1,19** <br/>
BAUCHSPECK **1,19** <br/>
DORNFELDER **0,99**<br/>
CLEMENTINEN **2,49**<br/>
L&M BLUE **3,50**<br/>
L&M BLUE **3,50**<br/>
SUMME EUR **14,84** *<br/>
BAR **50,00**<br/>

RUCKGELD EUR **35,16**<br/>
“ENTHALTENE MEHRWERTSTEUER A<br/>
MWST NETTO<br/>
**7,00** % **0,45** **6,40**<br/>
**19,00** % **1,28** **6,71**<br/>
SUMME MWST **1,73** **13,11**<br/>
EDEKA HANDELSGFSELLSCHAFT<br/>
NORDBAYERN-SACHSEN-THURINGEN MBH<br/>
STEUERNUMMER: 257/115/30471<br/>
QUITTUNG<br/>
NUTZEN SIE DIF EDECARD<br/>
PUNKTE_SAMMELN+PRAMIEN ERWERBEN<br/>
THR EINKAUF WARE UNS<br/>
1 BONUSPUNKTE WERT GEWESEN !<br/>
08.12.07 16:27 37589 48 4 8500<br/>
FS BEDIENTE STE: H. SEUFERT :<br/>
VIELEN DANK FÜR IHREN EINKAUF!<br/>
AUF WIEDERSEHEN IM E-CENTER<br/>
UNSERE ÖFFNUNGSZEITEN FÜR SIE:<br/>
MONTAG-SAMSTAG: 0800-20 . 00UER<br/>
```

---

The informations I want to obtain are bold.

#### Tried RegExp:

First I tried the following RegExp:

```
/(([\d]{1,2})(\,|\.)[\d]{2})/g
```

I choose this one, because

- I am looking for more than one match, therefore /

  (...) /g

  - My prices got one or two digits in the beginning, therefore `[\d]{1,2}`
  - After the first to digits, there is either a dot or a comma, therefore `(\,|\.)`
  - In the end, there are two digits, therefore `[\d]{2}`

[image: I got this output]

As you can see part of the date is a match, which I don't want.
Right now I don't mind the part after MWST Netto to match.

### My approach to the problem

My idea was to look for the dot. So I tried adding
[^.] before and after my RegExp

[image: Then I got this output]

As you can see my problem is still there.  I don't understand why 6,40 and 6,71 is not a match anymore as there is no dot before or after.

Does anyone got an idea what to try next? I was thinking about and *AND-Statement*, so I would use my first RegExp and then exclude anything that looks like a date.
But I'm not sure how to that.

I would really appreciate any tipps or ideas you have. If there is anything unclear or you need more information, please do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/(?:^|[^.\d])(\d{1,2}[,.]\d{2})(?![.\d])/g
```

and grab the contents of Group 1. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jykcvf/1).

**Details**

- `(?:^|[^.\d])` - start of string or any char other than `.` and digit
- `(\d{1,2}[,.]\d{2})` - Group 1: 1 or 2 digits, `.` or `,`, two digits
- `(?![.\d])` - no `.` or digit immediately to the right is allowed.

[JS demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/b4ukmdv7/):

```js
var text = "BT em \r\nSCHWEINFURT _OSKAR-VON-MILLER-STR.6 \r\nRADIESCHEN 0,59 \r\nKAESEAUFSCH. 1.39 \r\nBAUCHSPECK 1,19 \r\nBAUCHSPECK 1,19 \r\nDORNFELDER 0,99\r\nCLEMENTINEN 2,49\r\nL&M BLUE 3,50\r\nL&M BLUE 3,50\r\nSUMME EUR 14,84 *\r\nBAR 50,00\r\n\r\nRUCKGELD EUR 35,16\r\n“ENTHALTENE MEHRWERTSTEUER A\r\nMWST NETTO\r\n7,00 % 0,45 6,40\r\n19,00 % 1,28 6,71\r\nSUMME MWST 1,73 13,11\r\nEDEKA HANDELSGFSELLSCHAFT\r\nNORDBAYERN-SACHSEN-THURINGEN MBH\r\nSTEUERNUMMER: 257/115/30471\r\nQUITTUNG\r\nNUTZEN SIE DIF EDECARD\r\nPUNKTE_SAMMELN+PRAMIEN ERWERBEN\r\nTHR EINKAUF WARE UNS\r\n1 BONUSPUNKTE WERT GEWESEN !\r\n08.12.07 16:27 37589 48 4 8500\r\nFS BEDIENTE STE: H. SEUFERT :\r\nVIELEN DANK FÜR IHREN EINKAUF!\r\nAUF WIEDERSEHEN IM E-CENTER\r\nUNSERE ÖFFNUNGSZEITEN FÜR SIE:\r\nMONTAG-SAMSTAG: 0800-20 . 00UER";
var rx = /(?:^|[^.\d])(\d{1,2}[,.]\d{2})(?![.\d])/g;
var m, res = [];
while (m = rx.exec(text)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Th0rne Note that the other posted solution is not generic and you might need to adjust it later to exclude more and more contexts while my solution handles next to all edge cases. If you do not want to match numbers glued to words, just add word boundaries, `/(?:^|[^.\d])\b(\d{1,2}[,.]\d{2})\b(?![.\d])/g`

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use an alternation to match the format that you don't want and then capture in a group what you do want:

`\d+\.\d+\.\d+|(\d{1,2}[.,]\d{1,2})`

**Explanation**

- `\d+\.\d+\.\d+` Match pattern that you don't want to capture (or for example `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}` if you want to be more specific)
- `|` Or
- `(\d{1,2}[.,]\d{2})` Capture in a group 1 or 2 digits, a comma or dot and then 2 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nGJbba/1)

```js
const regex = /\d+\.\d+\.\d+|(\d{1,2}[.,]\d{2})/g;
const str = `BT em
SCHWEINFURT _OSKAR-VON-MILLER-STR.6
RADIESCHEN 0,59
KAESEAUFSCH. 1.39
BAUCHSPECK 1,19
BAUCHSPECK 1,19
DORNFELDER 0,99
CLEMENTINEN 2,49
L&M BLUE 3,50
L&M BLUE 3,50
SUMME EUR 14,84 *
BAR 50,00

RUCKGELD EUR 35,16
“ENTHALTENE MEHRWERTSTEUER A
MWST NETTO
7,00 % 0,45 6,40
19,00 % 1,28 6,71
SUMME MWST 1,73 13,11
EDEKA HANDELSGFSELLSCHAFT
NORDBAYERN-SACHSEN-THURINGEN MBH
STEUERNUMMER: 257/115/30471
QUITTUNG
NUTZEN SIE DIF EDECARD
PUNKTE_SAMMELN+PRAMIEN ERWERBEN
THR EINKAUF WARE UNS
1 BONUSPUNKTE WERT GEWESEN !
08.12.07 16:27 37589 48 4 8500
FS BEDIENTE STE: H. SEUFERT :
VIELEN DANK FÜR IHREN EINKAUF!
AUF WIEDERSEHEN IM E-CENTER
UNSERE ÖFFNUNGSZEITEN FÜR SIE:
MONTAG-SAMSTAG: 0800-20 . 00UER`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (m[1]) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't really are of the different groups and that is really helpful.